# C#: How to reduce multiple identical classes in two different xsd files into one class?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

ISO 20022 offers for every single message type [XML Schemas (xsd)](https://www.iso20022.org/iso-20022-message-definitions). In my project, I am working with the message types camt.053 and camt.054. Their schemas have around 240 complex and simple types. However around 220 types are identical to each other. Right now, to be able to import both message types, I import them into two different namespaces but this smells bad. It leads to a lot of redundant code when working with both message types.

Is there a way to import both message types into one namespace and reduce identical classes into one class?

Comment: You could create your own parent schema that has two items (camt.053 & camt.054).  Then the c# classes would be a merging of the two child classes.  You would use a XSD include : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_include.asp?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng xsd include seems to be the solution I'm looking for. Thanks. However there's a new issue coming up. When importing the self created parent schema with .NET XML Schema Definition tool, I receive the generating classes error: `The type has already been declared`. This is, as stated in the question, no surprise but seems to be an issue for the tool. But because we know that all double defined types are identical, is there a way to tell the tool to ignore that specific error?

Comment: The question has been asked a number of times.  The solution is to use a different namespace for each class which is what you originally had or write a utility to remove the duplicates.